# $\int (f * g)(x)\, h(x)\, dx = \int f(x)\,(g*h)(x)\, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convolution

I read the following convolution property in a proof of conservation of energy by Vlasov-Poisson. I tried to prove it without success.

$$\int (f * g)(x) \,h(x)\, dx = \int f(x)\,(g*h)(x) \,dx$$

With $(f*g)(x)=\int f(y)\,g(x-y)\,dy$

Is there someone who can help me to show this or give me a counter-example?

Comment: both sides are the product of the three fourier transforms

Comment: @User8128 in the penultimate expression you have g(z) h(z - y) and not g(z) h(y - z)

Comment: @mathworker21. What did you mean by the product of the three Fourier transform ?

Comment: @Nelson You're right, and what I have written has a mistake anyway. I will delete my previous comment.